# WebAPI Empty 500 Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am having an issue with WebAPI return an empty 500.

Here's the data classes.

```
public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool IsAnonymous { get; set; }

    public int ReviewId { get; set; }
    public Review Review { get; set; }
}
public class Review
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Topic { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool IsAnonymous { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Here's come code from the ReviewRepository.cs

```
public Review Get(int id)
{
    return _db.Reviews.Include("Comments").SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == id);
}
```

And the code from ReviewController.cs

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
{
    var category = _reviewRepository.Get(id);
    if (category == null)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, category);
}
```

No matter what I do, the response back from /api/reviews/1 is a 500 error. When debugging, the category is correct with all of the comments loaded.

I tried `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;`, but that didn't help. I am at a loss here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing it's because you have a circular object graph, which will cause a serialization error.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#handling_circular_object_references

Comment: That helps for sure. Object graph for type 'Reviewed.Models.Comment' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue. In addition to the GlobalConfiguration policy, you may need to include the following in your web.config.

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Still nothin' coming through just an empty 500. :(

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the serialization of `ICollection<Comment> Comments` or `Category Category`.